# Web Services API Key

Tags: php, ios, swift, security

I have a PHP server with some *.php* files. Swift iOS application send *POST* request to server and get some response in *JSON*. PHP files on server do some work with *MSQL*.

**The question is:**
*How to provide good security when do some request?*

I thinking to create some `let API_KEY = "dakhye8k3id9"` and send it with request to server. But is it secure? (Decompilers ect.). Maybe there is some other approach?

To give some string tokens is also not good idea because I store it in `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: Any method you choose is just access obfuscation. There's always a way to intercept calls or extract secretes from an app (given enough incentive). Prefer a SSL client certificate for authorization if feasible.

Comment: Intercept - yes. However I am talking about call api from php server. In api I have request which add subscription to user. And parameters - userId and subscId. Anyone can add subscription  knowing their id and sbscId.